# Problems with variadic function

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu, variadic-functions

I have the following function from some legacy code that I am maintaining.

```
long getMaxStart(long start, long count, const myStruct *s1, ...)
{
   long     i1, maxstart;
   myStruct *s2;
   va_list  marker;

   maxstart = start;

   /*BUGFIX: 003 */
   /*(va_start(marker, count);*/
   va_start(marker, s1);

   for (i1 = 1; i1 <= count; i1++)
   {
      s2 = va_arg(marker, myStruct *);           /* <- s2 is assigned null here */
      maxstart = MAX(maxstart, s2->firstvalid);  /* <- SEGV here */
   }

   va_end(marker);
   return (maxstart);
}
```

When the function is called with only one myStruct argument, it causes a SEGV. The code compiled and run without crashing on Windows XP when I compiled it using VS2005. I have now moved the code to Ubuntu Karmic and I am having problems with the stricter compiler on Linux. Is anyone able to spot what is causing the parameter not to be read correctly in the var_arg() statement?

I am compiling using gcc version 4.4.1

**Edit**

The statement that causes the SEGV is this one:

```
start = getMaxStart(start, 1, ms1);
```

The variables 'start' and 'ms1' have valid values when the code execution first reaches this line.

Comment: What does the code you're calling it with look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As written, when you pass in only one `myStruct` argument, `s1` is bound to that argument and your `va_list` will be empty.  Then, the first thing you do in the loop is to get the argument from that empty list, hence the NULL.

If you require at least one argument and want the compiler to type-check that for you, you'd have to do something like this:

```
long getMaxStart(long start, long count, const myStruct *s1, ...) {
    ...
    va_start(marker, s1);
    maxstart = s1->firstvalid; /* actually use s1 this time! */
    for (i1 = 1; i1 < count; i1++) /* different from your code */
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Otherwise, you're better off just removing `s1` from the function definition like Potatoswatter mentioned:

```
long getMaxStart(long start, long count, ...) {
    ...
    va_start(marker, count); /* not a bug */
    maxstart = -1; /* pick something resonable for your app */
    for (i1 = 0; i1 < count; i1++)
    { 
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: @karnastan: +1 for the lucid explanation

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit suspicious that `s1` is unused. Does `count` include `s1`, i.e. the total number of pointers passed in? Perhaps you want to eliminate `s1` and use `va_start(marker, count)`.

**EDIT**: Given the clarification in the comments, the fix is certainly

```
long getMaxStart(long start, long count, /* const myStruct *s1, */ ...)
{
   long     i1, maxstart;
   myStruct *s2;
   va_list  marker;

   maxstart = start;

   va_start(marker, count);

   for (i1 = 1; i1 <= count; i1++)
   {
      s2 = va_arg(marker, myStruct *);
      maxstart = MAX(maxstart, s2->firstvalid);
   }

   va_end(marker);
   return (maxstart);
}
```

The legacy code used `s1` to clarify what `...` meant, but since it interferes with the operation of varargs, you need to comment it out.

Comment: s1 IS used - its the 5th statement in the function definition.

Comment: The old code was indeed using va_start(marker, count) - which you can see have been changed (commented out). The compiler was given warnings to the effect that the second argument to the va_start() macro was not the last item in the known list - I corrected this.

Comment: @morpheous: `s1` is "used" as a placeholder by `va_start`, but its contents are discarded. Eliminate the compiler warning by erasing the declaration of `s1`, not by passing it to `va_start`.

Answer (score 0):

`va_start` takes a `va_list` argument and the last argument just before the variadic arguments begin. You call `va_arg` to get the first argument after the one you specified in `va_start`, or the next argument after a previous call to `va_arg`. In your case, you have told it that `s1` is the last argument before the variadic arguments with `va_start(marker, s1)`, so when you call `va_arg`, it will try to get a *4th* argument to your function call, but there is no 4th, so you get some strange behaviour.

You are invoking `va_arg` prematurely because if you supply `1` for your `count` argument, it will still enter the loop, even though you don't have enough arguments there. You should use:

```
for (i1 = 1; i1 < count; i1++)
```

But, if you do this, the value `s1` is never used. Go with Karmastan's answer.